# webView help-Error Page INTERNET WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, android-manifest

My AndroidManifest.xml file contains
the Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="permission.android.INTERNET" />
```

and my webview has no problem displaying a custom error page but wont load Urls like my website

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="permission.android.INTERNET" />
```